# FireStore Recycler adapter doesn't show object on position 0

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

i'm making a project which shows number of objects 
that i need to choose by position

the problem is that on firestore for example i see 4 objects 
and on the recycler ob my app i see 3 objects starting from position 1

a picture to show the problem:

[image: link to the picture]

this is the adapter class:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.netanel.iaiforme.R;
import com.netanel.iaiforme.pojo.Worker;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WorkerListsAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Worker, WorkerListsAdapter.WorkerViewHolder> {

    private  OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    private  OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener;

    private ArrayList<Worker> workerArrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    public WorkerListsAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Worker> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WorkerViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Worker worker) {
        holder.tvName.setText(worker.getName());
        holder.tvLast.setText(worker.getLast());
        holder.tvPhone.setText(worker.getPhone());
        holder.tvEmail.setText(worker.getEmail());
        holder.tvPersonalNumber.setText(worker.getPersonalNumber());
      /*  holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
//                    addWorkerToAc(workerArrayList2 , worker);
                }
            }
        });

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (!isChecked){
//                    removeWorkerFromAc(workerArrayList2 , worker);
                }
            }
        });*/
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public WorkerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.manage_worker_single_cell, parent, false);
        return new WorkerViewHolder(v);
    }

    public class WorkerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private LinearLayout layout;
        private TextView tvName, tvLast, tvPhone, tvEmail, tvPersonalNumber;
        CheckBox checkBox;

        WorkerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mw_chkbox_layout);
            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name_mw);
            tvLast = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_last_mw);
            tvPhone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_phone_mw);
            tvEmail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_email_mw);
            tvPersonalNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_personal_number_mw);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chkbox_worker_mw);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && onItemClickListener != null){
                        onItemClickListener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);
                    }
                }
            });
        }


    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot , int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        this.onItemClickListener = listener;

    }

  /*  public interface OnCheckedBox{
        void onCheckedChanged(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
    }
    public void setOnItemChecked(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener  listener){
        this.onCheckedChangeListener = listener;

    }

    public void removeWorkerFromAc(ArrayList<Worker> workerArrayList , Worker worker){
        workerArrayList.remove(worker);
    }
    public void addWorkerToAc(ArrayList<Worker> workerArrayList , Worker worker){
        workerArrayList.add(worker);



    }*/
}
```

and this is the fragment which i show the recycler on my app:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.netanel.iaiforme.R;
import com.netanel.iaiforme.pojo.Worker;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WorkerListsFragment extends Fragment{

    CheckBox checkBox;
    private static FirebaseUser auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference workerRef = db.collection("WorkerList");
    private WorkerListsAdapter adapter;


    public WorkerListsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView(View view) {

        Query query = workerRef.orderBy("personalNumber", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Worker> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Worker>()
                .setQuery(query, Worker.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new WorkerListsAdapter(options);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_worker_list);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new WorkerListsAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
                Worker worker = documentSnapshot.toObject(Worker.class);
                String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
                String path = documentSnapshot.getReference().getPath();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Position: " + position + " ID: " + id , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

//            adapter.setOnItemChecked();
    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_worker_lists, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        setUpRecyclerView(view);
        MoveToAcSelect(view);






    }
    public void MoveToAcSelect(View view){
        FloatingActionButton moveToacBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.move_to_ac_btn);
        moveToacBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                // TODO: 10/06/2020 Bundle with workerArraylist
//                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                Fragment fragment = new AircratsListsFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

}
```

thank for every help :)

Comment: What does the `personalNumber` field hold in Firestore?

Comment: personalNumber of the worker
like an id
not the id of firestore

Comment: Is `personalNumber` a `int` or `string`?